# Using existting LayoutParams doesn't show anything

Tags: java, android

i have layout to show list of loaded image from user's galery. First, in the layout there's default ImageView. If user load new image, i get the default image's LayoutParam then delete the default ImageView, then put the copied LayoutParam to the new loaded image then put the ImageView to screen. The problem is that the new ImageView's doesn't show anything whereas i have duplicate the default ImageView's LayoutParam. Here's the code.

**activity_view_product.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#eee">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivNoImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/noimage"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibAddImage"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ViewProductActivity.java**

```
private void chooseImageFromGalery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        ImageView ivImage = new ImageView(this);
        int size = ((int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)*75;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lyParam = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.ivNoImage).getLayoutParams();
        //LinearLayout.LayoutParams lyParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(75, 75, 1);
        Log.i("zihad", "layout param : "+lyParam.width);
        Log.i("zihad", "layout param : "+lyParam.height);
        Log.i("zihad", "layout param : "+lyParam.weight);
        Glide.with(ViewProductActivity.this)
                .load(imageUri)
                .error(R.drawable.noimage)
                .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .into(ivImage);
        lyImage.addView(ivImage, lyParam);
        ivImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        try {
            if (imageLoadedBitmap.size() == 0) {
                lyImage.removeView(findViewById(R.id.ivNoImage));
                imageLoadedBitmap.add(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]